# Listener Dynamic Config, listening to different types of MQ

Tags: asynchronous, apache-kafka, message-queue

**Background**

Hi, I am building an `AsyncExecutor` during my work. Currently, it pulls `message` from `Kafka`. (I am new in the field)

**Demand**

We want to refactor it as an infra or interface. Is there a way to let `AsynExecutor` dynamically listen to different types of MQ, such as `RabbitMQ`, `RocketMQ`, and `Kafka`?

**Idea**

Maybe, an abstract class or interface `IListener` could let others extend/implement and dynamically set the MQ type and address? I am not sure if it makes sense.

If not, is it due to different types of MQ? Should I limit to `kafka` with dynamic `brokers` config?

Comment: What language are you using? Assuming Java, Spring Cloud Streams or Apache Camel already offer this abstraction

Comment: Thanks, I am using java. I will check Spring Cloud Streams or Apache Camel.